# Identical for loop doesn't seem to be working

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I'm trying to solve a coding challenge from Free Code Camp.

**Diff Two Arrays**

Compare two arrays and return a new array with any items only found in one of the two given arrays, but not both. In other words, return the symmetric difference of the two arrays.

*[1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] should return [4].*

*[1, "calf", 3, "piglet"], [1, "calf", 3, 4] should return ["piglet", 4].*

My code is below:

```
 function diffArray(arr1, arr2) {
        var arr1Key = [];
        arr1Key = arr1;

        for (i = arr1.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            for (j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
                if (arr1[i] === arr2 [j]) {
                    arr1.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
        }

        for (k = arr2.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
            for (l = 0; l < arr1Key.length; l++) {
                if (arr2[k] === arr1Key[l]) {
                    arr2.splice(k, 1);
                }
            }
        }

        var newArr = [];
        newArr = arr1.concat(arr2);
        return (newArr)
    }

    diffArray([1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

I know it's probably not perfect/optimal, but what I primarily want to know is why my first series of for loops (using i & j) works perfectly. Meanwhile, my next series of for loops (using k & l) is a nearly identical copy of the first, but after some testing I found that only the k for loop works. The l for loop isn't working, and I don't understand why.

I've been staring at this thing and tinkering with it for what feels like forever and I just don't understand.

Comment: I wonder if it's because arr1Key and arr1 point to the same data - any changes to arr1 will change arr1Key - was that the intention?

Comment: No that wasn't the intention! Is that how it works in Javascript? How can I make a copy that isn't affected by changes to arr1?

Comment: `arr1.slice(0)` will copy the array

Comment: `arr1Key = arr1.slice();`

Comment: Awesome, thanks @JaromandaX. If you post that as an answer I'll be happy to accept it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You are splicing the arrays while looping through them, splicing can make them grow or shrink and you don't want that because you are using the array's `length` to loop.

Comment: Yeah, I ran into that issue on a different challenge. That's why I'm looping backward through the array being spliced!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you think you clone `arr1` by writing `arr1Key = arr1;`

This does not clone but creates a reference to `arr1`, so `arr1.splice(i, 1);` changes also `arr1Key`.

Just change the line     `arr1Key = arr1;` into  `arr1Key = arr1.slice();`